# Appium how to find and get the text of an element that changes such as a user's balance

Tags: selenium, appium

[image][image]

[image]

I'm trying to find the element on my app that shows the balance text of how much a user has.
The element does not have a content-desc and the text can easily change because it's the user's balance.
Could anyone show me different methods of how I can get the balance text with this?

Comment: Your code trials please

Comment: @DebanjanB I have no code trials. I have no idea how to locate an element like this.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to go with xpath here. Say find all the text views and either get this element by index, or search for a one which starts with $ or something.

If its an app that is being developed, then its a good idea to check with developers to add content-desc here.

Comment: Actually he did answer the question, but he didn't provide an example.  The index value will be unique for the class so you can use an xpath that specifies the class and the index, period.  You don't really need to check for the text value, that part was incorrect.  Try `//android.widget.Textview[index='0']` I'm not sure that the index number needs to be surrounded by quotes, but I'm fairly certain it does.  I'm upvoting the answer.

Comment: @BillHileman Don't assume that this answered my question because it did not.
There are multiple "Textview" elements that have 0 indices. From your solution, how does it know which "Textview" to look for the 0 index?

Comment: Based on the very limited info you gave, I have no way of knowing that.  The indices are unique for each level.  You gave me no indication what the entire structure is.  You'll have to select the ViewGroup you want, then the TextView within it.  But without seeing the whole uiautomator screen I can't be of much help.

Comment: @BillHileman sorry for the lack of information. I have updated it with a new screenshot of a higher level view of the UI automator.

Comment: Assuming each ViewGroup is an account, there's likely a way to navigate to that specific node using resource-id or some other method, then just continue the xpath to the next level, etc., as needed.  If there's a pattern, like after the account group there is always three sub-groups, and the third is always the balance, you could code your locator accordingly and get one or an entire array.  The new screenshot does help but without being able to see each node's properties, I can't suggest an xpath, but I think you get the idea?